# Change report page orientation

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services

I created a report on MS Reporting Server. I want to change report page orientation programmatically. I mean when the report view loads the report, I want to set the page orientation value of the report from .net code. How can I do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Page orientation is handled via the `InteractiveSize` (Width / Height) property of the Report. As far as I know, you cannot set those to an expression, so I don't think it's possible to change the orientation dynamically.

The only alternatives would be

- programmatically change the RDL (which is just an XML file under the covers) and updating it just before rendering (not something you'd want imho)
- creating your own rendering extension that bypasses the InteractiveSize (not trivial, I believe)

Not very simple alternatives, alas.